# ¿Como vaciar label al seleccionar un valor diferente en combobox?

Tags: c#, windows-forms

Tengo un formulario con un **combobox** compuesto por Localidades, 2 **botones** (Mostrar y Salir) y un **label** que muestra la ubicación en el combo y nombre de la localidad correspondiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que necesito es, que si hay una localidad seleccionada como el ejemplo de la imagen, al cambiar la selección de la localidad, se vacíe el mensaje.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No se si lo he entendido bien, pero ¿quieres que al seleccionar un valor que no es el que estaba ya seleccionado se borre el contenido del label?

Si es así el código anterior te valdría con una pequeña variación

```
private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //En esta comparación supongo que solo es el texto del combobox lo que se copia en la label
        //si es una frase tendrias que "currarte" la comparación(muy facil) 
        if (label1.Text.equals(comboBox1.Text)) 
        {
            label1.Text = "";
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Según entendí, quiere que al momento de seleccionar una de las opciones del combobox, en el label se muestre el mensaje con la localidad seleccionada ¿no?

Podría usar el evento SelectedIndexChanged, luego tomar el texto del combobox y  concatenarlo  con el mensaje, luego enviar este al label.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Está bien tu respuesta, pero en este sitio se prefiere siempre que se pegue el código relevante para la respuesta en lugar de una captura de pantalla. Un saludo

Comment: No no es ese mi problema, lo que yo necesito es que al cambiar de seleccion en el Combobox el label se vacíe, como bien explicite en el problema. **al cambiar la selección de la localidad, se vacíe el mensaje.**